# PowerEdge 1950 Generation III is slow when equipped with 64GB

Tags: dell-poweredge

The PowerEdge 1950 Generation III can accept 64GB of memory in 8 units if 8GB, however, everything about it seems incredibly slow. BIOS takes about an hour to boot and memtest86+ proceeds at an unusually slow pace. DIMMs are identical in brand and type. What is the fix for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried a BIOS upgrade?  1 hour bios boot would indicate a problem.

Comment: Check the memory type is compatible with the board also.  The spec sheet states they should be 667MHz FBD type.

Comment: Show us the memory model or part number.

Comment: @Matt, a BIOS upgrade fixed the slow BIOS boot problem. The memory is PC2-5300F. Strangely, the BIOS reports 63.75GB instead of 64GB.

Comment: @H2ONaCl - Is it resolved then?

Comment: @Matt, yes. If you post an answer, I can select it. It's very disappointing that a Gen III unit was likely shipped from Dell with a BIOS that results in an hour long boot. Either they knew about it and did not care or they simply never tried it. That's astonishing because one of the reasons for designing the Gen III was to raise the memory limit.

Comment: Lot of Servers can only run with reduced bus frequency when fully packed with (non registered) DIMMs, however that would not make it that slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had it happen before that sometimes servers are shipped with an out of date BIOS.  So despite the spec sheet telling you it supports x, y or z, when you configure it with the specific option it either doesn't work or produces a bunch of errors.

So, that obviously is always my first recommendation is to ensure you're running the latest BIOS.  In your case, you've indicated from my comment that this has resolved the issue.